# Radioactive gold in Goldfinger

Tags: james-bond, goldfinger

In the 1964 movie, Goldfinger tries to make the entire gold reserve of Fort Knox radioactive for 58 years (through Cobolt and Iodine), although this sounds quite clever, what do you think would happen if this scenario played out in the real world (let's say in 2015). Obviously the gold wouldnt be useless since it's still gold, although radioactive, and let's remember the reserve is only a reserve. The US can choose whether to confirm or deny the circumstances of the gold. Particularly, I'm interested what effects would this scenario potentially have through a economical, political and diplomatic perspective?

Comment: This sounds like an essay assignment, are you wanting people to do your homework for you?

Comment: The movie also claims Fort Knox is the largest gold depot in the world, apparently by a sizeable margin, which in reality it isn't. It isn't even the largest in the US: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Reserve_Bank_of_New_York_Building#Vault. So waiting 60 years would not be that much trouble, NY could deal with anything in between. @TheWanderingDevManager 's answer below is much more pressing: the fact someone managed to detonate a nuke on US soil would do much more damage to the economic (and political and social) status quo than a bit of irradiated gold.

Comment: I always laugh at the glee with which Bond announces his figures of just how impossible it is to steal the gold in Fort Knox (as worked out in his head), as per Fleming's original plot.  One of the few times the movie version is superior to the original book, and their solution of using a dirty bomb is indeed "truly inspired".

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager That was indeed a clever change.

Comment: *the gold wouldnt be useless since it's still gold* – Gold **is** useless (at least in comparison to its value), radioactive or not. Its value is mainly artificial.

Comment: The main product of the neutron activation of gold is the nuclide Au-198. This nuclide is indeed radioactive; however, its half-live is only 2.7 days. Therefore, the gold itself would not be radioactive for long. Certainly, the gold would also be contaminated with other fission products, activation products, and even hot particles from the bomb; however, gold, as a noble metal, can easily be decontaminated (simply cleaned, recast, or, if necessary, chemically separated).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Actually there is one thing it's quite useful for: electrical contacts. It's pretty good at conducting electricity (not as good as copper or silver) and is very resistant to corrosion (better than copper and silver).

Comment: @DanC: Hence “in comparison to its value”. If it were only for that usage, gold wouldn’t be that expensive.

Comment: Wrzlprmft: Say that the dollar was rendered useless, then you wouldnt even be able to trade by gold if it was radioactive, that's what i meant.

Comment: The Wandering Dev Manager: did you have home work like this? boy, that would have been great.

Comment: Loong: interesting. never thought that the gold could be decontaminated that easily, but it makes sense. so you are saying that one could wait for a month or so until the activity of Au-198 has converged enough and then recast it to get rid of any non gold isotopes?

Comment: @The Wandering Dev Manager: which part exactly sounds like an essay? wouldnt that apply to every question on stackexchange then?

Comment: "what effects would this scenario potentially have through a economical, political and diplomatic perspective?" sounds to me like an essay question.

Comment: @The Wandering Dev Manager

Answer (score 3):

I think even now it would play out as in the film. It's not that Goldfinger is quietly making the gold radioactive, there is a nuclear bomb involved, which would be slightly difficult to conceal the explosion. If anything it could be worse, other countries may assume ANY reserve is radioactive, so all reserves may decrease in value.

Comment: I also forgot about the fact that other countries besides the US stash their gold at Fort Knox. Surely they would want to know what happened to their gold.